# excel cell reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, extjs4

I have a combobox and a textbox in EXTJS 4.

```
else if (record.get("type") === "CELL_VALUE" && record.get("apply_before") === true)
    {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Field Validation", "I am Validating the CELL VALUE COMBO VALUE"); //alert message for testing only, this is where validation will occur
    }
```

In this scenario, "type" is a standard combobox and "appy_before" is a checkbox. If type = Cell Value and apply_before is checked, I need to validate a text box (range_from) contains a valid excel cell location, and that a second text box (range_to) is empty and if validation passes, set isValid = true, else isValid = false.

I know part of it should be as follows:

```
else if (record.get("type") === "CELL_VALUE" && record.get("apply_before") === true)
    {
            if (rangeFrom != (A1 - XFD1048576)**problem here**) || (rangeTo != null)
                    isValid = false;
    }
```

can anyone please provide a little more direction please as I have no clue how to check for the valid cell location where the range of cells can be anything from

```
A1 (first possible valid cell) to XFD1048576 (the last possible valid cell)
```

Comment: I have been directed toward the possibility of using an ASPOSE function:

    CellsHelper.cellNameToIndex 

but have no idea how to implement this to do what I want to do...

Comment: update to question:

The field (rangeFrom) needs to validate against a range of cells from

A1 to XFD1048576

(first valid worksheet cell) to (last valid worksheet cell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together a little validation function for you:

```
function validateRange(coordinate) {
    // A little input validation
    if (typeof coordinate != "string" || !coordinate.length) 
        return false;
    // Find the first occurrence of a digit
    var startIndex = coordinate.search(/[\d+]/);
    // The column is the part from the beginning up until the first digit
    var column = coordinate.substring(0, startIndex).toUpperCase();
    // The row is the remainder of the string
    var row = parseInt(coordinate.substring(startIndex), 10);
    // The column is sortable alphabetically so we can check its range,
    // and the row is numeric so we can check it's range as well
    return (column >= "A"   && row >= 1) && 
           (column <= "XFD" && row <= 1048576);
}
```

Give it a whirl:

```
var str = "XFD100000";
var result = validateRange(str);
```

Applied to your context:

```
if (!validateRange(rangeFrom)) {
```

I don't know exactly how fool-proof this is, but maybe it would give you a good starting point.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2rJN/2/)**

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote up, but I accepted your answer as it has worked great and has passed initial testing. Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateRange(coordinate) {
    if (typeof coordinate != "string" || !coordinate.length) 
        return false;
    var startIndex = coordinate.search(/[\d+]/);
    var column = coordinate.substring(0, startIndex).toUpperCase();
    var row = parseInt(coordinate.substring(startIndex), 10);
    return (column >= "A" && ((column.length<3 && column <= "ZZ") ||(column.length==3 && column <= "XFD")) && (row >= 1 && row <= 1048576));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details to your answer and how is it different/better than the previous one?